# React Native Expo: RTL not working on actual Device but works fine on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, react-navigation, expo

I am using I18NText library for RTL & translation. 
I see different results on Expo app running on a device vs an iOS simulator running on my machine. Both simulator and Expo app have device language has Arabic(RTL).

I see the "< Back" button on the header as expected(on top right side) on the simulator but the Expo app does not flip the position of back button(still shows on top left).

Same goes for Tab bar icons sequence. It shows in correct order in the RTL simulator but not on the device.